# Using the HAVING Clause with GROUP by to Return Unique Records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, count, sql-server-2014

Good day all,

I am having difficulty understanding the mechanics of the GROUP BY AND HAVING clause and was hoping for some advice.

I am trying to query two tables - **PRODUCTS** and **ORDER_ITEMS**. The **PRODUCT_ID** column is used to link these two tables.

I wish to view products which have been ordered from a certain supplier (filtered using the **SUPPLIER_ID** column which is in **ORDER_ITEMS**); have been successfully ordered before (**ORDER_STATUS** 6 in **ORDER_ITEMS**);and which have not been deleted (**RECORD_DELETED** column in **ORDER_ITEMS**). I only use the **PRODUCTS** table to show the name of the product. Furthermore I only want distinct products returned, meaning I want to exclude any results which duplicate the **PRODUCT_ID** column

This is the query that I am using:

```
SELECT 
       PD.PRODUCT_ID,
       PD.PRODUCT_NAME,
       PD.BARCODE,
       PD.SUPPLIER_BARCODE,
       COUNT(PD.PRODUCT_ID) AS COUNTED,
       ODI.ORDER_ITEM_ID
FROM PRODUCTS PD
INNER JOIN ORDER_ITEMS ODI
ON PD.PRODUCT_ID = ODI.PRODUCT_ID
WHERE ODI.SUPPLIER_ID = 34359738399
  AND ORDER_STATUS = 6
  AND ODI.RECORD_DELETED = 0
GROUP BY PD.PRODUCT_ID,PD.PRODUCT_NAME,PD.BARCODE,PD.SUPPLIER_BARCODE,ODI.ORDER_ITEM_ID
HAVING COUNT(ODI.PRODUCT_ID) = 1
ORDER BY PRODUCT_ID ASC
```

Unfortunately this is returning *502* records with many of them duplicating the **PRODUCT_ID**. If I remove the **ORDER_ITEM_ID** column from the query *175* records are returned. These 175 records are products that meet the criteria given above. The problem is that I also need to pull the **ORDER_ITEM_ID** from **ORDER_ITEMS** (along with some other columns).

I vaguely understand that when I include **ORDER_ITEMS** the query is going to group the data by the **ORDER_ITEM** column and so will count the **PRODUCT_ID** values based on each individual **ORDER_ITEM_ID**. This results in there always being a count of 1 for each product.

How does one get around this? Also, is there a more suitable way of carrying out this task which would allow me to include one **ORDER_ITEM** record for every duplicated product? Rather than omitting them altogether as I am doing above?

This is some of the data that is returned by the query above:

```
PRODUCT_ID,PRODUCT_NAME,BARCODE,SUPPLIER_BARCODE,COUNTED,ORDER_ITEM_ID

34359738628,ADCORTYL INTRA-ARTIC/DERMAL 10MG/ML 5ML,5099627022132,5012712000037,1,34359755708
34359739609,ARTELAC 3.2MG/ML EYE DROPS SOLN,5099627456722,5027519008933,1,34359741719
34359739626,ASACOLON 500MG SUPPOSITORIES,5099627516587,5015313012737,1,34359742783
34359739767,ATROVENT 250MCG/1ML UDV NEB SOLN,5099627639637,5012816012561,1,34359738421
34359739770,ATROVENT 500MCG/2ML UDV NEB SOLN,5099627460293,5012816012592,1,34359743524
34359739893,AZOPT 10MG/ML EYE DROPS SUSP,5099627831543,5015664002753,1,34359749091
34359739893,AZOPT 10MG/ML EYE DROPS SUSP,5099627831543,5015664002753,1,34359749687
34359739893,AZOPT 10MG/ML EYE DROPS SUSP,5099627831543,5015664002753,1,34359749715
34359739893,AZOPT 10MG/ML EYE DROPS SUSP,5099627831543,5015664002753,1,34359754053
34359740053,BACTIGRAS MED DRSS 10CMX10CM STERILE GMS,5099627672368,5000223421984,1,34359748101
34359740062,BACTROBAN 2% OINTMENT,5099627053914,5099211003165,1,34359755226
34359740558,BETNOVATE RD CREAM,5099627005692,5099211001642,1,34359752422
34359740558,BETNOVATE RD CREAM,5099627005692,5099211001642,1,34359738487
34359741045,BISODOL ANTACID TABS,5099627057707,5014398001438,1,34359750542
34359741995,BROLENE 0.1% EYE DROPS SOLN,5099627006323,50982790,1,34359746555
34359741995,BROLENE 0.1% EYE DROPS SOLN,5099627006323,50982790,1,34359751650
34359741995,BROLENE 0.1% EYE DROPS SOLN,5099627006323,50982790,1,34359751783
34359742132,BURINEX 1MG TABS,5099627551328,5702191004212,1,34359749705
34359742152,BUSCOPAN 20MG/ML SOLN FOR INJ,5099627006620,5012816018532,1,34359749083
```

In the example above, several records were returned with duplicate **PRODUCT_ID** values e.g ASACOLON 500MG SUPPOSITORIES

Comment: So how you want to present it? Comma separated list with `ORDER_ITEM_ID`?

Comment: can you provide some sample data?

Comment: Yes, that would be fine. I am running this on SQL Server 2014.

Comment: Why use different product_id's in SELECT COUNT(PD.PRODUCT_ID), but HAVING COUNT(ODI.PRODUCT_ID)? Use the same one in both places!'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `GROUP_CONCAT/LISTAGG` equivalent in `SQL Server`. You can use `XML, STUFF and correlated subquery` as replacement.

If `PRODUCT_ID` is `UNIQUE` you can use:

```
WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT 
       PD.PRODUCT_ID,
       PD.PRODUCT_NAME,
       PD.BARCODE,
       PD.SUPPLIER_BARCODE,
       ODI.ORDER_ITEM_ID
  FROM PRODUCTS PD
  JOIN ORDER_ITEMS ODI
    ON PD.PRODUCT_ID = ODI.PRODUCT_ID
  WHERE ODI.SUPPLIER_ID = 34359738399
    AND ORDER_STATUS = 6
    AND ODI.RECORD_DELETED = 0
)
SELECT PRODUCT_ID,
       PRODUCT_NAME,
       BARCODE,
       SUPPLIER_BARCODE,
       [COUNTED] = COUNT(PD.PRODUCT_ID),
       [ORDER_ITEM_ID] = STUFF((SELECT CONCAT(',' , ORDER_ITEM_ID)
                                FROM cte c2
                                WHERE c2.PRODUCT_ID = c1.PRODUCT_ID
                                ORDER BY c2.ORDER_ITEM_ID
                                FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '')
FROM cte c1
GROUP BY PRODUCT_ID,PRODUCT_NAME,BARCODE,SUPPLIER_BARCODE
HAVING COUNT(PRODUCT_ID) = 1
ORDER BY PRODUCT_ID ASC;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo_SimplifiedVersion`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/397868)**</kbd>

Otherwise correlate using multiple columns:

```
SELECT CONCAT(',' , ORDER_ITEM_ID)
FROM cte c2
WHERE c2.PRODUCT_ID = c1.PRODUCT_ID
  AND c2.PRODUCT_NAME = c1.PRODUCT_NAME
  AND ...
ORDER BY c2.ORDER_ITEM_ID
FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '')
```

Comment: That was just what I needed

Comment: Could I ask you to explain what it is that the concat function is being used for?I understand that both xmpath and concat are used for concatenating strings. Also is there an advantage with this method over just assigning the select statement directly to [ORDER_ITEM_ID] as in [ORDER_ITEM_ID] = SELECT ...

Comment: @Xivilai Concat is for getting comma separated string, XML combine it to one string and STUFF removes first comma. More info https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/